# Can't manually install opensans on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing, texlive, ubuntu

I'm trying to use the font opensans for a document. This works great on Ubuntu 13.04, but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04.3. The reason for this was pretty easy to figure out, because Ubuntu 13.04 includes the font in a system package. So I installed opensans using CTAN (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/opensans), and followed the instructions in the documentation. I did these steps:

- Download the ZIP and extract this to */usr/share/texmf* (I want to install systemwide)
- Run **mktexlsr**
- Run **updmap --enable Map=opensans.map**
- Because I want it installed systemwide, I also tried **sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=opensans.map**

None of these commands gives an error. But unfortunately, this didn't work completely. I can use the normal `opensans` font now just fine. It just fails on italics/bold text. A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}

\begin{document}
Testing \textbf{bold} and \textit{italics}!
\end{document}
```

The error I get is this:

```
$ pdflatex mwe.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/opensans/opensans.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/slantsc/slantsc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))) (./mwe.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/opensans/ot1fos.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdf
tex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+57/600 --dpi 657 OpenSans-Bold-01
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for OpenSans-Bold-01.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file OpenSans-Bold-01): Font OpenSans-Bold-01 at 657 n
ot found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This was done with the same user that ran the above commands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks! I had a look and I *think* I updated my question to match the starter page.

Comment: your question indeed is a good one :)

Comment: It seems the TeXLive from Ubuntu is TL2009. Please [update to TL2013](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: Okay, I took the plunge and updated our servers to the latest Ubuntu version. While that's not something I hope to do again anytime soon, it did allow me to install the `texlive-extra-fonts` package which contains OpenSans. So I guess this works...

Could you make your comment into an answer @MartinSchröder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the TeXLive from your Ubuntu version is from 2009, which is at this time four releases ago (i.e. especially in these features can be considered to be outdated). Please [update to the latest release](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).